# how to get usercontrol in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I get a handle on my user control in JavaScript?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" Enabled="False" />
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /></div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageDefault = {
            uc: document.getElementById("<%=WebUserControl1.ClientID%>"),
            btn1: document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID%>"),
            init: function() {
                this.btn1.onclick = function() {
                    uc.setAttribute('Enabled', 'True'); //uc is null at this point
                };
            }
        }
        pageDefault.init();
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What if you set `Enabled` to true -- can you get a handle to your user control?  I think if `enabled` is false, the control isn't rendered.  Could be wrong there, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference the ClientID like you did, the JavaScript needs to be inside the UserControl, not the page. If you want to use it the way you have it here, you'll need to expose the clientId as a public property from your user control:

```
public string userCtlClientId
{
  get{return userCtl.ClientId;} 
}
```

and modify your script:

```
document.getElementById('<% =WebUserControl1.userCtlClientId%>');
```